# need help getting azure media services encoded video to play in HTML5/DASH

Tags: html, azure, azure-media-services, mpeg-dash

As a question this is pretty simple... but it is not really a question... it is more of a how do I do this?  Before you continue on the rest of the post boils down to this:  "Can you please offer an example of a Azure Media Services encoded video, downloaded from and not deployed on Azure Media Services (AMS), and playing in DASH in HTML5"...

---

Considering Microsoft is dropping support for Expression and that Silverlight is not going to be in Edge... my company wants to pursue a solution where we use Azure Media Services (AMS) to encode video, download it to our network, and then serve it on webpages hosted on IIS on our intrAnet.  I feel I am making progress... but have some issues...

Two approaches...

1. In DASH - I am able to get the samples to work in code samples I have found.  But I cannot get the video I have downloaded to play. At best I just get "Unknown Error" in the player where the video would be.

Here is an idea of how this code looks now:

```
    <!-- DASH-AVC/265 reference implementation -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/dash.all.js"></script>

<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.0.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.0.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

```html
    <!-- DASH-AVC/265 reference implementation -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dash.all.js"></script>

    <link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.0.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.0.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // setup the video element and attach it to the Dash player
        function setupVideo() {
            //var url = "http://wams.edgesuite.net/media/MPTExpressionData02/BigBuckBunny_1080p24_IYUV_2ch.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)";
            //var url = "http://localhost/temp/1/dash2/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.ism/manifest";
 
            var url = "http://localhost/temp/1/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.ism/manifest";

            //var url = "http://wams.edgesuite.net/media/MPTExpressionData02/BigBuckBunny_1080p24_IYUV_2ch.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)";
            debugger;
            var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
            var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
            player.startup();
            player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoplayer"));
            player.attachSource(url);
        }
    </script>
```

2. Azure Media Player.. (I generally assume this is not compatible with things not hosted on AMS and am more strongly pursuing the DASH solution) -- In this case I get a blue tv screen thing with a crack in it with an error code below.  The error code is... "A network error caused the video download to fail part way. (0x2020019f)

Some things to note:

1. I have verified the validity (in one way, but that way may not be applicable here) in the sense that it is recognized by IIS Manager as a "Smooth Streaming Presentation"
2. IIS Media Services is installed.
3. When using the DASH Validator (on the .ism file) at http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=605  I get

```html
Start XLink resolving
=====================

XLink resolving successful Valid


Start MPD validation
====================

Line:Col[2:111]:cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element ‘smil’.
MPD validation not successful – DASH is not valid! Invalid
```

Comment: Note I have also tried this with (format=mpd-time-csf) after /manifest... same thing

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set up a streaming server (IIS Media Server) on your local machine. Our team developed IIS Media Server on premises a few years ago, and we are no longer making update on this on premises technology. Instead, we make improvement on Azure Media Services, which hosts streaming server in the cloud. New feature such as DASH support, dynamic packaging are not included on IIS Media Server.

I am just wondering why don't you consider streaming from Azure Media Services, and Azure Media Player you are using only works with Azure Media Services. By Feeding in /manifest as a streaming URL, Azure Media Player will detect which formats best playback on your platform based on your technology preference, and it will request different format. The server will dynamically package the stream based on multiple rate Mp4 (which you need to encode to). For more information, please refer to our [MSDN documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dynamic-packaging-overview/) and please let me know if you have any questions.